# Difference between dates not a whole number

Tags: r, difftime

Why is this not giving me a whole number of days?

```
difftime("2015-04-22", "2014-10-30")

Time difference of 173.9583 days
```

Comment: I appreciate I can round this up, but I'm confused as to the default behaviour.

Comment: You can use `?difftime` to see the documentation. `difftime("2015-04-22", "2014-10-30", units="days")`

Comment: @JasonWang it gives the same result

Comment: Does it work on yours - if so, guess it's something to do with my computer then?

Comment: What's your R version?

Comment: R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)

Comment: .9583 * 24 = 23. Could it be Summer time? Wella wella wella

Comment: Ahh - clock changes maybe...

Comment: On R 3.2.2, even the code in the question yields 174.

Comment: I assumed since there wasn't a time component the same would be applied to both dates, but that wouldn't matter if clock changes are applied automatically - how do I stop that?

Comment: Does this work? `difftime(as.Date("2015-04-22"), as.Date("2014-10-30"))`

Comment: @JasonWang - tried 3.3.2 and get the same problem. It's definitely(?) a clock change thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Date` class to avoid the extra complexity of timestamps, daylight savings time, etc.

```
> as.Date("2015-04-22") - as.Date("2014-10-30")
Time difference of 174 days
```